# IdentityServer4 Authorization header authentication

Tags: identityserver4, basic-authentication, api-key, .net-core-3.0

I'm new to .Net, so I'm struggling a bit to understand how to approach the machine 2 machine authentication and authorization. Here's what I'm trying to do.

We have a Library that will call an API for a resource but the call must be authorized, so there's also an IS4. Each part is a separate project in a solution and runs in Docker.
We'd like enforce the Library to provide an API Key with every request to API in `Authorization` header. Then we'd like the API to check for

- API Key is valid
- API Key belongs to a user with correct set of claims and/or scopes

If that's all OK then accept the incoming request or send `401 Unauthorized` otherwise.

We're trying to do this with IS4, because in the future we'd like to use features like Single Sing-On, delegation, etc.

This m2m is the first step and even though it looks simple, we're having a hard time making it work.

By default m2m communication requires `ClientCredentials` Grant Type in IS4. But using it requires 2 steps: make a request for access token and then use this access token to access API resource.

Getting access token requires providing the `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` and `Scope` but we want to use a single API Key instead.

Is it possible to wrap those 2 things together somehow?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to user some client credentials to issue a very long lived reference token - which is in effect an API key. 

Is this something you need to be able to configure again and again or is it a one-time backoffice type exercise?

Comment: There will be many users but the API Key won't change often. Still, we need to be able to revoke the key. Can you elaborate more on this, please?

Comment: I know the question is old, but I needed something similar and here what I end up doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63699424/identityserver4-using-apikey-or-basic-authentication-directly-to-api